# How to read data form an UART

Tags: c, function, uart

I have a sensor connected via uart to an mcu. The output of the sensor is ascii chapital R followed by four ascii character numbers and ends with a carriage return. e.g. R1234CR

Below is code for reading one character at a time from the uart.

I'm trying to write a function that when it detects the capital R and it puts the next four characters in an array.

I have most of the function written below but I'm struggling with the logic flow.

Also how can I return the array?

Thanks

Comment: A few things that should help with the logic: there is an endless loop; `ndx` is static, do you indent to call `getdata` more than once?; the return type of `getdata` is `int`, does this meet your requirement of returning the array, do you need an `int` returned from `getdata`

Comment: Don't use magic values. And an 'if'-loop does not exist.

Comment: And C does not have symbolic constants except enum-constants. `const` does not declare a constant! C is not C++!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want..I shifted some of the code and made some changes..I couldn't compile it because of course I don't have and real UART interface..Hope it will work..

I scanned the UART received data continuously until all the data are fetched or -1 is received. **However I did not encounter any carriage return because I am expecting that you are interested only 5 bytes of data** Feel free to change this code as you would need..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char receivedChars[5] = {0};
    bool status = getdata(receivedChars);
}


char getchar(void) {
    int ret;    
    if ( (ret = ti_uart_read(TI_UART_0, &c)) == TI_RC_OK)
        return ((char) c);
    return -1;
}

bool getdata(char *receivedChars) {
    int count = 0;
    char retchar;
    char buffer[5] = {0};
    while(1){
        retchar = getchar(); 
        if ((retchar == 'R') && (count == 0)){
            // It means the first occurance of 'R'
            buffer[count] = 'R';
            count++;
        }else if ((count > 0) && (count < 5) &&  isdigit(retchar) != 0){
            buffer[count] = retchar;
            count++;
        }else if(retchar == -1){
            // Assumed that -1 means error in recieving the data from UART
            return false;
        }else{
            continue;
        }

        if (count == 5){
         strncpy(receivedChars, buffer, count); 
         return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At the first if loop `if (retchar != 'R') {continue;}`, It will not execute the lower logic for all cases other than 'R'. It will not fill the array for an input sequence of e.g. `R1234`

Answer (score -1):

You have two things that you are trying to do in the code

> I'm trying to write a function that when it detects the capital R and it puts the next four characters in an array

and

> //if the chars are 1-9 then write them to the array

Doing both is sometimes contradictory. So you need to decide what is it you need to accomplish.

The first one is more complex, so I will help you with that one.

```
void getdata(char *receivedChars) 
{    
    static uint8_t detected, ndx;
    int retchar;
    retchar= getchar();

    if ((retchar == 'R') && (detected == 0))
    {
        detected = 1;
        ndx = 0;
    }

    if ((detected == 1) && (ndx < 4))
    {
       receivedChars[ndx] = retchar;
       ndx++;
    }

    if (retchar == '\r'){
      receivedChars[ndx] = '\0';
      ndx = 0;
      ti_uart_writebuffer(UART_0, (uint8_t *)receivedChars, sizeof(receivedChars));
    }
}
```

Edit: Changed type to void and added `ti_uart_writebuffer` call in the `getdata` function. This call should now be removed from the `main` function.

Comment: What ate you returning from the `getdata` function?

Comment: Hi guys, please see my post above, I had to reply to the question as I could not fit it in a comment. Thanks

Comment: @Rishikesh Either you change the return type of `getdata` to void or return something..or else your program will be syntactically wrong.

Comment: @MayukhSarkar The type should be changed to void, I am just confirming from OP as to whether this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje, should I call `getdata()` in a `do while(1)` loop in `main()`. The data from the sensor continuously comes in at 9600 baud. Wouldn't I need to continuously call `getdata()` in main() or have a `do while(1)` inside 'getdata()`?

Comment: @RishikeshRaje What I just want to do is continuously receive the sensor data, when the array is full then write it out over putty continuously.